# Recursive reboots on VMware machines

Tags: powershell, vmware, vsphere

I want to automate a recursive reboot of a set of VMs every Sunday, using the vSphere CLI.

My current code performs a one time reboot on one server, I could write multiple lines or include multiple servers in the same code but I am looking to involve a sequence in this.

I do not want the second VM to be rebooted before the first one successfully reboots and comes up.

```
Import-Module VMware.VimAutomation.Core
Connect-VIServer -Server <server> -User <user> -Password <password>
Restart-VM <vm_name> -RunAsync -Confirm:$false
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough about vSphere CLI, but I suppose if you remove `-RunAsync` from your code the cmdlet would wait until the reboot finishes. As this is a reasonable expectation from a async operation to not wait for the operation to end. So if you remove it it should wait for the operation to end.